# Converting docx/odt to PDF using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ms-word, converters, jspdf

I have a node web app that needs to convert a docx file into pdf (using client side resources only and no plugins). I've found a possible solution by converting my docx into HTML using docxjs and then HTML to PDF using jspdf (docx->HTML->PDF).
This solution could make it but I encountered several issues especially with rendering. I know that docxjs doesn't keep the same rendering in HTML as the docx file so it is a problem...

So my question is do you know any free module/solution that could directly do the job without going through HTML (I'm open to odt as a source as well)? If not, what would you advise me to do?

Thanks

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: @SunilLama I didn't find...

Comment: @ncohen Hello friends, recently encountered this problem domain and wanted to share my findings. Firstly, check out https://www.zamzar.com/ and https://convertio.co/ they are both a robust 3rd party API conversion service. I did a bit of reverse engineering in order to figure out how they were able to render DOCX to HTML and here's what I found. They'd first go from DOCX to PDF with libreoffice or unoconv as zarkone documented below but then would go from PDF to HTML with some secret sauce called https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX, which is a one of a kind open-source conversion tool!

Answer (score 15):

As you already know there is no ready-to-use and open libs for this.. You just can't get good results with available variants. My suggesition is:

1. Use third party API. Like https://market.mashape.com/convertapi/word2pdf-1#!documentation
2. Create your own service for this purpose. If you have such ability, I suggest to create a small server on node.js (I bet you know how to do this). You can use Libreoffice as a good converter with good render quality like this:

   `libreoffice -headless -invisible -convert-to pdf {$file_name} -outdir /www-disk/`

   Don't forget that this is usually takes a lot of time, do not block the request-answer flow: use separate process for each convert operation.

   And the last thing. Libreoffice is not very lightweight but it has good quality. You can also find notable `unoconv` tool.

As of January 2019, there is [docx-wasm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativedocuments/docx-wasm), which works in node and performs the conversion locally where node is installed.  Proprietary but freemium.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still looking for something working on the client.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want server side conversion?

Comment: Right, I would like my app to be totally autonomous.

Comment: Can't you use api? You mean "totally autonomous" - without internet connection? There are many providers who can convert x -> y with an api call. Just google it

Comment: Edited to add link to docx-wasm (disclosure: I have an interest)

Comment: @JasonPlutext what's that status of NativeDocuments? Any chance you'd be willing to open source that project? (also, feel free to ignore my other messages on github / twitter)

Comment: I second the question o @zelusp - it's seemed like the perfect one and only one out there

Answer (score 3):

It appears that even after three years ncohen had not found an answer. It was also unclear if it had to be a free (as in dollars) solution.

The original requirements were:

> using client side resources only and no plugins
>
> Do you mean you don't want server side conversion? Right, I would like my app to be totally autonomous.

Since all the other answers/comments only offered server side component solutions, which the author clearly stated was not what they wanted, here is a proposed answer.

The company I work for has had this solution for a few years now, that can convert DOCX (not odt yet) files to PDF completely in the browser, with no server side component required. This currently uses either asm.js/PNaCl/WASM depending on the exact browser being used.

https://www.pdftron.com/samples/web/samples/viewing/viewing/

Open an office file using the demo above, and you will see no server communication. Everything is done client side. This demo works on mobile browsers also.

Comment: is there a source code that I can check or learn from ?

Comment: @MirzaAndriamanamisoa This is a closed source paid commercial solution. Online demo is here: https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/