# React .docx to .pdf conversion before upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, docx, file-conversion

Has anyone converted docx files into PDF files on the front-end before making a request to the back-end? I'm using react-dropzone and need to convert any docx files to pdfs before uploading them.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why not upload as-is and do the conversion server-side?

Comment: There is a requirement for conversion to be handled on the front-end

Comment: check out `docx-wasm` maybe? possible duplicate of [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593886/converting-docx-odt-to-pdf-using-javascript)