# How to convert a blob that contains docx, ppt or xlsx into a PDF in javascript or react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, react-pdf

Input will be  a URL which points to the file, from which I can extract the blob.

I'm trying to render MS Office file types in a web application  within an IFrame.

Comment: I great that you know what to do, but what is your question?

Comment: How to convert a blob that contains docx, ppt or xlsx into a PDF in javascript or react js?

Comment: Check if this answer your question: [Converting docx/odt to PDF using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593886/converting-docx-odt-to-pdf-using-javascript)

Comment: Looking for an opensource library, PDFTron is a paid one.